# Images downloaded are blank images, instead of actual images

Tags: python, image, lxml, python-requests

For learning purposes I am trying to download all the posts images of a Buzzfeed article.

Here is my code:

```
import lxml.html
import string
import random
import requests

url ='http://www.buzzfeed.com/mjs538/messages-from-creationists-to-people-who-believe-in-evolutio?bftw'
headers = headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
        'From': 'admin@jhvisser.com'
}

page= requests.get(url)

tree = lxml.html.fromstring(page.content)

#print(soup.prettify()).encode('ascii', 'ignore')

images = tree.cssselect("div.sub_buzz_content img")

def id_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size))

for image in images:
    with open(id_generator() + '.jpg', 'wb') as handle:
        request = requests.get(image.attrib['src'], headers=headers, stream=True)

        for block in request.iter_content(1024):
            if not block:
                break
            handle.write(block)
```

What is retrieved are images all 110 bytes in size, and viewing them is just an empty image. Am I do something wrong in my code here that is causing the issue? I don't have to use requests if there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: Try adding an user-agent to your request. A lot of webservers reject requests without user-agent. It's customary to leave an email-address in the user-agent when crawling to let the owner of the server contact you if they don't approve the crawling.

Comment: @SteinarLima Still no luck with adding the user agent. I updated my OP with the new code. I believe I implemented the user agent correctly?

Comment: On another note: You shouldn't keep such images on your computer. They'll make you look stupid.

Comment: @SteinarLima I am aware that it is stupid. I am keeping them safely nested away on a server. I am actually only doing this so that I can re-upload images to imgur. Getting practice with scraping and the imgur api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely at the source code of the webpage you are trying to crawl, you'll see that the image url's you want are not specified in the `src` attribute of the `img` tags, but in the `rel:bf_image_src` attribute.

Changing `image.attrib['src']` to `image.attrib['rel:bf_image_src']` should fix your problem.

I didn't manage to replicate your code (it claims that `cssselect` isn't installed), but this code with [BeautifulSoup](http://crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) run smoothly on my computer, and download all 22 pictures.

```
from itertools import count
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
from time import sleep


url ='http://www.buzzfeed.com/mjs538/messages-from-creationists-to-people-who-believe-in-evolutio?bftw'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Non-commercical crawler, Steinar Lima. Contact: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21616904/images-downloaded-are-blank-images-instead-of-actual-images'
}

r = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(r))
c = count()

for div in soup.find_all('div', id='buzz_sub_buzz'):
    for img in div.find_all('img'):
        print img['rel:bf_image_src']
        with open('images/{}.jpg'.format(next(c)), 'wb') as img_out:
            req = urllib2.Request(img['rel:bf_image_src'], headers=headers)
            img_out.write(urllib2.urlopen(req).read())
            sleep(5)
```

Comment: @Fogest It's for formating the string using [str.format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). I use `c` as a [`itertools.count`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count), and by using `'images/{}.jpg'.format(next(c))`, the filenames will start at `0.jpg` and count upwards.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense. Is `count()` essentially equivalent to setting an integer to 0 and then incrementing it each time the loop runs? If so, is there an advantage to using `count()`? Using incrementing numbers is probably a better solution than using random strings like I did.

Comment: Yes, it is. Just check out the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count). It's really easy :)